# Rotation between keyframes

Tags: python, interpolation, blender, keyframe

I need to full rotate the camera around some object starting at frame 1 and ending at frame 1147. To interpolate automatically, I need to use keyframes. How do I insert keyframes at frames 1 and 1147 and rotate the camera between these keyframes using python script? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

An easy way to rotate a camera around an object is to add an empty at the same location as the object of attention, parent the camera to the empty, use a track to constraint to keep the camera pointed at the object and then rotate the empty.

This can be done in python as -

```
import bpy
import math

scene = bpy.context.scene
cam = scene.camera

bpy.ops.object.empty_add()
target = bpy.context.active_object
target.name = 'focus point'
target.location = bpy.data.objects['focusObj'].location
cam.parent = target

tc = cam.constraints.new(type='TRACK_TO')
tc.target = target
tc.up_axis = 'UP_Y'
tc.track_axis = 'TRACK_NEGATIVE_Z'

scene.frame_current = 1
target.rotation_euler = (0,0,0)
target.keyframe_insert(data_path="rotation_euler")
scene.frame_current = 1147
target.rotation_euler = (0,0,math.radians(360))
target.keyframe_insert(data_path="rotation_euler")

for fc in target.animation_data.action.fcurves:
    fc.extrapolation = 'LINEAR'
    for kp in fc.keyframe_points:
        kp.interpolation = 'LINEAR'
```

You will need to adjust the name "focusObj".

By setting the interpolation to linear you will get a constant rotation speed, not an ease in and out at the start and end. Setting the extrapolation to linear means it will continue to rotate endlessly.